# android webview with html5 video Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)

Tags: android, html, video, webview, html5-video

I have a very strange problem with my webview loading a page containing html5 video. the webview crashes with a:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)
```

This is a really strange problem that happens only on 4.0.x, on 4.3 it works well.

my video gets loaded with:

```
this.loadDataWithBaseURL(webContainer.getBaseUrl(), webContent, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

and hardware acceleration is set to true.

the weirdest is that when i delete the controls (controls="false" or no controls at all) the webview gets loaded.

I checked on a lot of other questions that had the same fatal signal but nothing really help. Does anyone know how to handle this error? maybe I'm missing some web settings?

thanks in advance !

Comment: Fixed the issue here. the webContent was doing wierd stuff (recharging elements) that broke the webview.

Comment: can you share the solution.

Comment: My html content was doing weird things in JS that was breaking the webview. I was fixed there I can't really share it as it's corporate part

Comment: no issues . I have also found my solution.